# What is different between $\frac{1}{1+\lambda x}$ and $\exp{(-\lambda x)}$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, functions, exponential-function

I want to choose a function $f(x)$ which has properties: $f(x)$ closes to $0$ when $x$ goes to $+\infty$ . I have two option for that

1. $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+\lambda x}$, where $\lambda$ is tuning parameter
2. $f(x)=\exp{(-\lambda x)}$

What is different between first and second options? Which one is better?

As my knowledge, I think main different is that fraction function is more smooth and gradually reduce than the exponential  function. Thank all

[image]

Comment: $\exp(-\lambda x)$ does not go to $1$ for $x \to \infty$.

Comment: I suppose the "close to $1$ when $x$ goes to $\infty$" is just a typo and you meant "close to $0$" there. Assuming $\lambda > 0$ - otherwise we wouldn't have the desired behaviour - the exponential decays much much faster than the rational function. What is better depends on what the task is.

Comment: Sorry, It is only close to zero